# extends CotrollerBase along with other controller in phalcon, I want to use the functions of postSmsController in SmsSentController

Tags: php, oop, phalcon

```
class ControllerBase
{

}


class postSmsController extends ControllerBase
{

}

class SmsSentController extends ControllerBase
{

}
```

How to extends CotrollerBase along with other controller in phalcon, I want to use the functions of postSmsController in SmsSentController, also want to use function of ControllerBase in both Controller classes. what should i do

Comment: Muhammad, this is not specific to Phalcon.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend one from another

```
// Base controller
class ControllerBase
{
    public function one()
    {

    }
}


// Extending. Offers one() and two()
class postSmsController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function two()
    {

    }
}

// Extending. Offers one() and two() and three()
class SmsSentController extends postSmsController
{
    public function three()
    {

    }
}

// Offers only one()
class otherController extends ControllerBase
{

}
```